# Python, PyQt5 возможно ли нарисовать прямоугольник не используя ООП?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qpainter, рисование

Нужно нарисовать прямоугольник, например красный и создать метод для изменения его размера не используя при этом объектно-ориентированный подход:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton


prg = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()
base_layer = QVBoxLayout()
rectangle_widget = QWidget()       # В этом виджете разместьить прямоугольник
base_layer.addWidget(rectangle_widget)
window.setLayout(base_layer)

window.show()
sys.exit(prg.exec())


def change_rectangle_size(width):  # этот метод должен менять размер прямоугольника
    pass
```

Comment: почему нельзя использовать ООП ?

Comment: Ну, во-первых, в вашем случае это не метод, а просто функция.

Comment: Во-вторых, что конкретно вы подразумеваете под "не использовать ООП"? ООП - это не какой-то конкретный приём или элемент языка. ООП - это методология разработки.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы пример не был завернут в класс.

Comment: @S.Nick это просто интерес, если можно без ООП - тогда мне так будет удобнее, если невозможно, прийдется потратить драгоценное время на изучение азов ООП. Python я выбрал как скриптовый язык, поэтому не уделял внимание ООП.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извините, но без азов ООП у вас ничего не получится!
Не смысле, что нельзя реализовать то, что вы задумали,
а в том, что этот подход очень ограниченный и по моему мнению неправильный.

Я вам предложу пример, который делает почти то, что вы спросили.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QSpinBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()

        self.w, self.h = 400, 200
        self.pen = QPen()              
        self.pen.setColor(Qt.green)
        self.pen.setWidth(3)               
        
        spinbox = QSpinBox()
        spinbox.setRange(100, 400)
        spinbox.setSingleStep(10)
        spinbox.setValue(100) 
        spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.change_rectangle_size)
        
        base_layer = QVBoxLayout(self)
        base_layer.addWidget(spinbox, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)        

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)    
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.drawRect(100, 170, self.w, self.h)    

    def change_rectangle_size(self, value):
        self.w, self.h = value, value/2
        self.update()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.resize(600, 600)
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо прийдется почитать об ООП в Python, тогда последний вопрос - в какой момент вызывается printEvent? Он отвечает за отрисовку, так? self.update() его вызывает?

Comment: @arachnoden и чем быстрее, тем лучше. `void QWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)` - Этот обработчик событий может быть повторно реализован в подклассе для получения событий рисования, переданных в event. Больше ... https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent и https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintevent.html